# Is someone halachically obligated if anesthetized? Comatose?

Tags: halacha, medicine, tashlumin, onen

If someone slept in until 1pm, they should daven a double Amida at Mincha, to make up for the Shacharis that they were obligated, but missed.

On the other hand, if someone was busy arranging for a relative's burial, and was busy doing so from before dawn until the 1pm burial, then they only daven a regular Mincha, as during the entire time of Shacharis, they were never obligated.

(I think by that logic, if someone was temporarily insane from dawn to noon, then recovered, they shouldn't have to make it up, because they weren't obligated.)

What if someone was in surgery and under general anesthesia from dawn till noon? Do they do a double Mincha? Or were they not obligated because they were far more than "just asleep"? Say someone comes out of a coma -- similar question?

(A Gett can be delivered on behalf of a husband who happens to be sleeping now; not on behalf of a husband who's gone insane, for instance. Okay then -- what if at the time the agent delivers the Gett, the husband is anesthetized? Or here's a troublesome case ... suppose it turns out that at the time the agent delivered the Gett, the husband was incredibly "high", "smashed", or drunk past the point of "recognizing their actions"?)

Comment: Or what about if someone had *techiyas ha'meisim*?

Comment: Part of me feels like every time I leave the house I should say תנו גט לאשתי to the first two guys I come across, because I don't want her to be an agunah if I get hit by a truck and end up in a coma.  (Another part of me says that that kind of paranoia is not psychologically healthy.)  Based on your question maybe it wouldn't even work.

Answer (score 1):

From the language of the SA [OC 108:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.108.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> טעה או נאנס ולא התפלל שחרית מתפלל מנחה שתים
>
> **One** who erred or **who, because of extenuating circumstances, did not
> pray Shacharit must pray Mincha** [Shmonei Esrei] **twice**

one sees than an אנוס (someone who is prevented to pray) has to pray twice once he is no more prevented.

R Abraham S. Abrahan in [Nishmat Avraham](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578195756.html) (vol. 1, p. 62) writes this applies to someone who was ill and unable to pray Shmonei Esrei because of this. I looked for specific rulings for anesthesia or coma but didn't see anything - which I take means the general rule applies there.

Note that someone who misses multiple prayers (e.g., a long anesthesia) can only compensate for the last one he missed ([OC 108:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.108.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

I confirmed the above with R Binyamin Tabady (a rosh beit midrash in Israel) who concurs.

Comment: If he wasn't a *bar daas*, he had no chiyuv whatsoever, so there's no tashlumin. I guess that's my question -- is he considered to have been a *bar chiyuva* at that time. (Non-bar-chiyuva is even less than anoos.) But I hear, you're reading it into the absence of the Nishmas Avraham ... could be.

Comment: See last line/edit - I checked this